# Writing Large Portions Of Code Then Debugging?

Tags: c++, programming-practices, debugging, time-management, technical-debt

Lately I have been writing a game engine, and I have been writing a lot of "foundation stuff" (standard interfaces, modules, a message system ect.), but I have noticed a pattern, a lot of the stuff is interdependent and I can not debug until everything is done, hence I do not debug for about 3 to 5 hours at a time. I am wondering if this is an acceptable practice for this part of the project, and if not, if anyone can give me some advice?

-----Update-----:

I downloaded some code metrics tools, and my programs cyclomatic complexity is 1.52 which as I understand it is good, and should correlate to high cohesion, if I am wrong please correct me/

Comment: How interdependant? Can you mock/stub out the other part so that you are able to test just one part?  You sound like you have very tight [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) which can be a bad thing.

Comment: Is it an acceptable practice to whom?  I'm fine with it.  If it takes you 3 hours, it takes you 3 hours.  You're probably saving time not going back and forth between development and debugging.

Comment: @MichaelT It is sort of like (example): The engine class is composed of instances of the module class and is pretty much meant to handle them. But both the engine class and the module base class require interfaces and stuff from the "core" (utility stuff). Or another example: I have a "message" class and a "mailbox" base class and I need some sort of management system to test them properly.

Comment: You don't need "some sort of management system to test them properly".  What does the mailbox class do?  If it interacts with another class, you can mock the other class and verify that the mailbox works as designed, before you have any implementation of the other class.

Comment: @kevincline True. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called coupling. You can reduce coupling by breaking everything into smaller pieces, which should increase the cohesion of each piece. It will make it easier and faster to develop and test each piece.

If you are developing something with dependencies on other pieces, try designing with Dependency Injection in mind. This should let you develop each piece individually, without needing to create all of its dependencies first.

Comment: Thanks! I was a tad worried about the cohesion of my engine, but I did not know how to deal with it.

Comment: Unit testing, especially with TDD, can help with the coupling and allow you to test much more rapidly.

Answer (score 2):

Stop. No really, stop. Stop and read about [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).

The system you are implementing will have a difficult time being tested, debugged, maintained, updated, etc.

Take TDD to heart and spend the time now to understand how TDD can drive your design to a system that can be tested, debugged, and maintained.

TDD has changed the way that I develop.